# How to make a DXL attribute that is true if the word "shall" exists in another attribute, in IBM Rational DOORS?

Tags: scripting, ibm-doors

Trying to make a DXL boolean attribute (called "Is Requirement?") true if the word "shall" exists in another attribute (called "Text"), and otherwise false.

In edit-mode on the DOORS module, I click Edit -> Attributes -> "Is Requirement?" -> Edit... -> check DXL attribute -> Browse... -> New, write the code -> Ok, close all windows, Tools -> Refresh DXL Attributes

```
Object o
for o in current Module do{

 if((o."Text") contains "shall")
  {
   o."Is Requirement?" = "True"
  }
 else
  {
   o."Is Requirement?" = "False"
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several aspects here:

- The code for a DXL attribute is the code for one specific object and one specific attribute, the object is available in the variable `obj`, the attribute  is available in `attrDXLName`. There is no loop over objects neither in DXL attributes nor in DXL layout columns.
- `contains` has the signature `int contains(Buffer b, string word, int offset)`, it operates on a Buffer, not on a string. You probably want to use `bool findPlainText(string s, string sub, int &offset, int &length, bool matchCase[, bool reverse])`
- `o."Text"` will return an object reference. But you want to check the *content* of the attribute. To get the content of a string attribute, you have to cast the object reference to string, e.g. by concatenating the reference with a string. You can use `obj."Text" ""`.
- Is there really an attribute "Text" in your module? Usually, people use the attribute "Object Text".

This changes your code to

```
int offset, length
bool matchCase = true
obj.attrDXLName = findPlainText (obj."Object Text" "", "shall", offset, length, matchCase)
```

Remember that the type of your DXL attribute must be boolean for this to work.

And last but not least: Are you sure that your condition "Text contains shall" is sufficient? What about all the words that contain "shall" (https://www.thefreedictionary.com/words-containing-shall)? There are some threads about this topic somewhere in the internet. Search for "Requirement DXL shall shallow". And: is "shall" enough? What about "may", "should", "must"?

Comment: Thank you very much for the thorough explanation. I don't think for DXL attributes you can edit booleans for pocket cases where, for example, the word "shallow" exists for a non-requirement and I want to manually make that False. Is there any way to run the DXL attribute, retain all the true/false's, and then turn it into a non-DXL attribute that I can manually edit?

Comment: Well, you could perhaps create a sort of "manual override" for the decision. Let's say you have an attribute "override is Requirement", type "Enumeration" with values "undefined", "yes", "no" with default value "undefined". For corner cases, the user would set the attribute to "yes" or "no". In your DXL Attribute "is Requirement?" you would check whether "override is Requirement" is "yes" or "no" and if so, set "is Requirement?" to "true" or "false". Only if it is "undefined", check for "shall" in the "Object Text".

Comment: But I guess, sooner or later, your requirements managers will be more comfortable if they have full control of whether an object is a requirement or not. Very often, companies create an attribute "manual ID", that the users fill with a number of their choice which is the official "Requirement Number". Then "is Requirement?" will be calculated as "true" if and only if "manual ID" has a value. This way is more intuitive than dependence on keywords like "must" and "shall".