# Looking at a attribute object and seeing if it has duplicates

Tags: ibm-doors

the code below works to check if a outlink has the word verified. More importantly it checks if each outlink has the code verified and returns verified only if all are matching.

if (value = "verified") display "verified" else value has "blank" display "blank".

```
string HVCRM_Status = ""
Link outlnk
string tmn = ""
bool Blank_Verified_Found = false
string Verification_Point = obj."Verification Point"

if (Verification_Point == "Yes")
{
    for outlnk in obj->"*" do
    {
        tmn = fullName target(outlnk)
        Object tgt = target(outlnk)
        if(matches("VCRM", tmn))
        {
            HVCRM_Status = probeAttr_(tgt,"Verification Status")
            //display "HVCRM_Status: " HVCRM_Status
            if (HVCRM_Status != "Verified")
            {
                Blank_Verified_Found = true
            }
        }
    }
    if (Blank_Verified_Found != true)
        //display "Status: Verified"
            display "Verified"
    else
        //display "Status: Not Verified"
            display "Not Verified"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the snippet I did not understand what exactly you are trying to do here.

Perhaps this helps:

- An Object has attributes.
- The attributes are defined for each module and have a datatype.
- Only attributes that exist can be used in DXL.
- Also: comparison for equality is done using `==`, not `=`
- `=` is used for assigning values to variables or to attributes

Let's say you have defined attributes with the names `"myattr"` and "`myOtherAttribute`" of type `string`.

- To get an *attribute reference* for the former , you state `o."myattr"`.
- To get the content of that attribute (of type `string`), you can concatenate the attribute reference with an empty string (`""`) or you can provoke an implicit typecast by assigning the attribute reference to a variable of type `string`.
- To *set* a value, give the value to the *attribute reference* with "`=`"

So, either

```
   if (o."myattr" "" == "Test") {
      o."myOtherAttribute" = "Good Morning"
   }
```

or

```
   string myAttrContent = o."myattr"
   if (myAttrContent == "Test")´ {…]
```

Your code uses the attributes "Attribute", "z", "TEST" and some attribute without a name (o."") (which of course does not exist).

With this information, rework your script and see whether you have additional questions

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for the detailed answer. I have tested this with my DOORS module and for the example above and using data in the module this does work. Originally I wanted to use a link go to a certain module get the object and attribute from that module. The main object has multiple links.  I have reworded my original question.

Comment: seems you are interested the content of the attribute "Verification Status" of objects one link level below. The code generated by the analysis wizard has the statement `s = probeRichAttr_ …`.  After this line,  `s` contains the content of the "Verification Status" of one linked object. I would create a boolean variable `bool bVerified=false` at the top of `showOut`. After `s` has been set, check whether it is "verified" and if so, set `bVerified` to `true`. Remove the `display`s in the middle of the loop. At the end of `showOut` display "verified" only if `bVerified` is `true`

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks I tried this. Problem I am currently having is confirming if 's' is returning verified if the attribute contains verified. I tried using wild cards with *s 'if (s == "verified"). This is because there are multiple verified that can be populated in the DXL attribute. Now the end result is when 'bVerified = true' then all cells display verified and when 'bVerified = false' all return blank.

Comment: if the code you posted is complete, then you don't call "showOut" any more and `bVerified` is never populated.  Perhaps the intention is unclear to me. I understand that you have a DXL attribute that shall contain the word "verified" if and only if at least one of the "Verification Status" of the directly out-linked objects has the value "verified", and if none of them is "verified", the DXL Attribute shall be blank. Correct?

Comment: In this context, I don't understand the sentence about wild cards. Are you looking for the perm `bool findPlainText(string s, string sub, int &offset, int &length, bool
matchCase[, bool reverse])` ? You can use this perm to check whether `s` contains the word "verified" somewhere in the text. (see an example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72553436/how-to-make-a-dxl-attribute-that-is-true-if-the-word-shall-exists-in-another-a/72555434#72555434)

Comment: Hi Mike, yeah that could be the best way to look though in my case I would looking for a blank space because any blanks will set the entire return to blank. I think I need to find what exactly the 's' is returning when blank. It might be a new link or one blank space. Will try and see how it goes. Thanks again

Comment: thanks Mike for the help reverted back to finding the outlnk with the above code and used the logic to get the right dispay